# JavaScript Retrieving the unique 'id' of div elements with just a class?

Tags: javascript, html

When making a JavaScript script to iterate through a set of elements with the same class name, you can alter each of their properties individually.

How does the script know which element to edit if they don't have unique IDs? If they do in fact have unique ID's, how do you retrieve them? Using `alert();` to display what is held in the node array from a simple `document.getElementsByClassName('');` seems to display the type of element.

Could I actually store these results in an array for later use?

If on the documents load, I fetch an array of elements with a certain class name:

```
<script>

var buttonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

</script>
```

Then iterate through this, and add the result at 'r' position to an object:

```
<script>

var buttonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
var buttonObject = {};

for(r=0;r<buttonArray.length;r+=1)
{
     buttonObject[buttonArray[r]] = [r*5,r*5,r*5];
}

</script>
```

Would I be able to find the array for each individual element with classname 'button' like so:

```
<script>

var buttonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
var buttonObject = {};

function changeCol(buttonID)
{
     var red = buttonObject[buttonID][0];
     var green = buttonObject[buttonID][1];
     var green = buttonObject[buttonID][2];
     buttonID.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")";
}

for(r=0;r<buttonArray.length;r+=1)
{
     buttonObject[buttonArray[r]] = [r*5,r*5,r*5];
     buttonArray[r].onclick = function(){ changeCol(this); };
}

</script>
```

I thought the `this` part of `onclick = function(){ changeCol(this); };` would hold the same unique ID as I stored in the buttonObject object, as the variable name that held the array?

Should this work? I can't seem to get it to on my web page, so instead, I used the buttons innerHTML in the buttonObject as the variable name that held the array for that object. The problem with that, is that I will probably need two or more buttons to have the same innerHTML.

Here's the webpage as it currently is: 
http://www.shadespeed.com

I need to re-make the script to allow buttons to have the same name.

Any tips / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

- Dan. :)

Comment: The keys of an object have to be strings, you can't use DOM elements as the keys.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Any way to concatenate a character with the DOM element?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have a deck of cards spread out on my desk, face up. I want to flip over all the red ones. I might do this:

```
desk.getCardsByColour("red").forEach(flipit);
// note, obviously not real JavaScript for a not real situation :p
```

So I scan through my cards, finding all the red ones. Then I flip them over. What you're asking is basically "how do I know which cards to flip over if they don't have unique IDs?" Well, do I *need* an ID to iterate through a collection of objects, in this case a set of cards? Of course not.

(Note that while cards in a deck *do* have a unique property in their content, let's just assume that's the element's content and not an `id` attribute, kay?)

Now, here's how I'd do what you're doing:

```
for( r=0; r<buttonArray.length; r++) {
  buttonArray[r].buttonObject = [r*5,r*5,r*5];
  buttonArray[r].onclick = changeCol;
}
function changeCol(button) {
  var red   = button.buttonObject[0];
  var green = button.buttonObject[1];
  var blue  = button.buttonObject[2];
  button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")";
}
```

Comment: Can you add a random array to an element?

Comment: Of course. Elements are just objects, and you can assign arbitrary properties to any object, therefore to any element.